# How to speed up "Getting printer information"?

Tags: printing, evince

Whenever I want to print a PDF document in evince, I'm always slowed down with the "Getting printer information" process. I was wondering if there was anyway to save the "printer information" locally somehow so I'm not slowed down by the network lookup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disable Listening on /var/run/cups/cups.sock in cupsd.conf, keeping only "Listen localhost:631". See comment #29 in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/475845

```
sudo perl -i.bak -pe 's/^(Listen .*cups\.sock)/#$1/' /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
```

If your application doesn't show any printers any more, restart it.

Comment: Can you explain what this change does? What is the socket /var/run/cups/cups.sock used for and how does disabling it affect the system?

Answer (score 1):

Set a static ip for the printer and put the printer in the hosts file.You could try fiddling with http://localhost:631