# Network printer stuck at "Getting printer information" from system GTK print dialog

Tags: networking, printing, gtk

At work we have a bunch of printers connected to a central CUPS server in the internal network.

Running Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity DE, whenever I try to print something in an application using the system's GTK print dialog as shown in the screenshot below, I see all available printers, some of them even with a status message like "no toner left". Whichever printer I select though, the "Print" button stays locked and the printer's status is shown as "Getting printer information..." forever.

[image: GTK print dialog: Getting printer information...]

The printers are working fine though, as I am able to print correctly through applications that do not use the GTK dialog, like Chromium, which has a print dialog built in. Only the GTK dialog is broken.

I found these old bug reports describing pretty much the same behaviour:

- [GTK print dialog does not allow printing and does not show options of a remote DNS-SD/Bonjour printer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gtk/+bug/1053891) (2012, fix released for Ubuntu 12.10 apparently)
- [Printer dialog stuck on "Getting printer information..."](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1378438) (2014, unresolved)

I also have read somewhere that the package `libnss-mdns` is required for this functionality, but was missing in some installations. However, I verified that I have version `0.10-7` of that library installed.

How else can I troubleshoot this issue? Any workarounds or fixes?

Answer (score 3):

Having same issue, in a much easier enviroment (single printer), on Ubuntu 18.x

Solved with

```
sudo perl -i.bak -pe 's/^(Listen .*cups\.sock)/#$1/' /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
```

source [How to speed up “Getting printer information”?](https://askubuntu.com/a/21338/209229)
. You may also refer to the very detailed [DebuggingPrintingProblems](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems)

Comment: For me, this also fixed an issue I had with gimp (NOT snap) where my network printer wasn't displaying at all (or maybe it's the restart of the cups service, but doubt it).

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this with "Add Printer" in the settings.

Somehow, the printer shows up twice. Once as an actually usable printer, once as a printer that needs its information retrieved.

[image]

Comment: Same thing on HP DeskJet 2700. Weird.